# GSOAP wsdl2h ssl build error

Tags: gsoap

I Try to generate .h files using gsoap, but i got error saying that I have to download the wsdl file and run again coz it contains ssl access.

Ok - I donwload it and re-execute the command but still on the same error.

How could I resolve it.

[image]

[WSDL Link](http://www.megafileupload.com/jkkI/services.wsdl)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Using a browser, download the .wsdl file and also download all .xsd files that the .wsdl file imports. Then run wsdl2h on these local file(s) starting with the .xsd files. If that does not work, then change the URIs in all  to refer to the local file (just the .xsd file name will do).
2. Rebuild wsdl2h using `cd gsoap/wsdl; make secure` to enable SSL support for HTTPS.

Option #2 won't work for Windows unless you have Cygwin installed and can run `make`.

Hint: use wsdl2h option -v to view its (verbose) output.

Comment: I went for #1 option (no rebuilding wsd2h parser).

When I open into IE the wsdl I see two schemas :
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://jaxb.dev.java.net/array" schemaLocation="https://10.3.11.22:8443/TWS3/services?xsd=1" />
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="T24WebServicesImpl" schemaLocation="https://10.3.11.22:8443/TWS3/services?xsd=2" />
</xsd:schema>

I downloaded respectively as services1.wsdl and services2.wsdl
I run wsd2h -o a.h services1.wsdl services2.wsdl and worked (I guess)

But when I tried the soapcpp2 I have No SoapClient.cpp or proxy files